# Is it possible to use jQuery $.when with the boolean flag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, synchronization

I have an ajax call that should be executed when and only when the certain flag is set somewhere else in the code.

I cannot make this call directly in the function that sets the flag because I do not need to  make this call each time when flag is set.

It is a bit hard to explain so the best illustration I can think of is something like:

The wolf can eat the Red Hat when and only when she is in her grandma's house.
However not every time she comes to this house, there is a wolf to eat her. From the other side each time when she is here and the wolf is here, the wolf will eat her.

I wonder, can I use $.when(theFlag) for this purpose?

```
var theRedHatIsHere = false;

function waitForRedHat()
{
.....
   theRedHatIsHere = true;
}

function wolfIsHungry(link)
{
   $.when(theRedHatIsHere)
   {
       $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "php/eatredhat.php?",
                data: ddd,
                async: false,
                success: function(msg){
                        console.log( "Eaten" );
                        window.location.href = link;
                }
        });                         
   }
}
```

Comment: There might be a way to do it with `$.when` (which expects a promise object, not a boolean), but why don't you just use an `if` statement: `if(theRedHatIsHere)` ?

Comment: I want to wait till it happens, because when it happens I need to make this call.

Comment: Don't make it too complicated. I would just call a function whenever you change the state (redhat or wolf here) and which makes the Ajax call when both are true.

Comment: Instead of setting `theRedHatIsHere = true;` how about firing custom event `$(document).trigger( "theRedHatIsHere" );`?

Comment: @freakish still the same problem, though a custom event is cooler(+1). Not each time the Red Hat is here she should be/can be eaten

Comment: @FelixKling I oversimplified my problem, it seems :-). But probably you are right, and 2 simple flags will do. However I still want to get an answer about $.when, as there are some sync IO issues involved.

Comment: @FelixKling: nope, it won't work as there is this link that is passed to wolfIsHungry() and I do not know of when the Red Hat state is changed, only when the wolf's state is changed. Obviously I can store it somewhere global, but I would prefer not to take this road.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use custom events or Publish/Subscribe pattern instead of bending $.when to do something that is not supposed to do.  It is a well known pattern, it helps decouple your components and you have the flexibility for example to have multiple subscribers to the event, stop listening to the event at some point or reacting to it only once.

Subscribe to a custom event with jQuery.on

```
$(document).on('WolfIsHome', function(){
   $(document).on('WolfGotHungry', function(){
       $(document).on('RedHatArrived', function()
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "php/eatredhat.php?",
                data: ddd,
                async: false,
                success: function(msg){
                        console.log( "Eaten" );
                        window.location.href = link;
                }
            });
      }
  });
});
```

whenever the wolf gets hungry, instead of setting that boolean value just raise that custom event:

```
$(document).trigger("WolfIsHome"); // trigger in your logic when the wolf is home

$(document).trigger("WolfGotHungry"); //trigger wolfhungry which will register a subscriber to RedHat arrival event

//and somewhere else in the code
// if RedHatArrived and Wolf is not hungry then nothing will happen 
// because there won't be registered subscribers to her arrival
$(document).trigger("RedHatArrived");
```

Comment: I know exactly when the wolf gets hungry, my problem is, when it happens, to wait till the Red Hat comes and then and only then to eat her.

Comment: it's still the same logic .. trigger an event called "RedHatCame" - as opposed to setting the boolean to true - and let the subscriber react to that event

Comment: see my edit to include RedHatArrived event that only get listened to if WolfGotHungry

Comment: There is a difference between **1)** get notified when the Red Hat comes and then to eat her, if I am hungry and **2)** when I am hungry, I will wait till she comes and then will eat her. In the first case he will probably eat her sometimes, in the second case he will eat her for sure sometimes.

Comment: what do you mean "sometimes", in both scenarios he will eat her if he gets hungry and she arrives afterwards .. I don't see the difference. The only problem with the logic itself is that it won't work if the wolf gets hungry after her arrival.

Comment: metaphorically speaking **1)** is the wolf running in the fields till he gets SMS "RH arrived". Then he runs to the gran's house, but probably she will be not here already when he gets there. **2)** is the wolf sitting in   the ambush waiting for her to arrive. BTW thanks for bearing with me.

Comment: sorry but your example didn't talk about running in the fields. The two variables you defined are whether 1. wolf is hungry or not 2. whether redhat is home or not. So *the wolf is in the house*. You could expand the example to cater for more events but the principle remain the same, it's about two decoupled components "RedHat" and "Wolf" reacting to changing events whatever they are.

Comment: From the question: **However not every time she comes to this house, there is a wolf to eat her**

Comment: ok my bad .. I added another event in the code sample for WolfIsHome. Again it is just concept of Pub/Sub I am presenting here, you can have any specifics but the concept remain the same.

Answer (score 2):

```
var theRedHatIsHere = $.Deferred();

function waitForRedHat()
{
.....
   theRedHatIsHere.resolve();
}

function wolfIsHungry(link)
{
   $.when(theRedHatIsHere).then(function() {
       $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "php/eatredhat.php?",
                data: ddd,
                async: false,
                success: function(msg){
                        console.log( "Eaten" );
                        window.location.href = link;
                }
        });                         
   });
}
```

One of drawbacks here is that you'll be able to trigger the request just once.

Comment: Were it possible to use this mechanism multiple times, that is exactly what I am looking for. Is there any option to "unresolve" theReadHatIsHere after it was resolved?

Comment: @Flot2011: nope. It's actually a feature, that deferred's state is immutable. So I doubt so

Comment: What if you had a module build them?

Comment: Is there a reason for `$.when` here? I think it can be eliminated since `theRedHatIsHere` is already a deferred.

Comment: @TravisJ - sorry, didn't get it. Can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

There is something you can do here. Instead of using a global value for `theRedHatIsHere`, you can save it in an input element. Like `<input type="hidden" id="theRedHatIsHere" value="0"/>`

Now once this value is updated, fire an event. You can bind it as:

```
$(function () {
    $('#theRedHatIsHere').on("change", function () {
        if ($(this).val() == 1 && wolfIsHungry == 1) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "php/eatredhat.php?",
                data: ddd,
                async: false,
                success: function (msg) {
                    console.log("Eaten");
                    window.location.href = link; // dont know where this link is being sent from
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

How does that sound?

Comment: As I said, not each time the Red Hat is here, the wolf is here to eat her. I can add a flag inside wolfIsHungry, to test that he is really hungry, but then I will end doing a lot of useless calls.

Comment: how are you determining that if the wolf is really hungry or not?

Comment: i am usually calling this function from the place where I know that.